# Fetching the Outlook Task's Data into Webpart using Graph Api call

Tags: sharepoint-framework, microsoft-graph, graph-api, office-graph, ms-graph-client

**I am using render function to make Graph Api call**

**I have created a function _outlookTask to fetch the outlook task's data**

**How to make Graph Api call with Selecting the HTTP method as GET and then, select beta as the API version in my function**

```
public render(): void {
this.context.msGraphClientFactory
  .getClient()
.then((graphclient:MSGraphClient): void=>{
  graphclient
  .api('/me/outlook/tasks')
  .get((error,user:MicrosoftGraph.OutlookItem,rawResponse?:any)=>{
  this.domElement.innerHTML = `
 <div>
 <div id="spListContainer">
 </div>
  </div>`;
 this._OutlookTask(tasks.value)
})
 })

}

private _OutlookTask(tasks: MicrosoftGraph.Message[]): void {
let html: string = '';
for (let index = 0; index < tasks.length; index++) {
  html += `<p class="${styles.description}">Tasks Through Outlook  ${index + 1} - 
${escape(tasks[index].subject)}</p>`;
}

// Add the emails to the placeholder
const listContainer: Element = this.domElement.querySelector('#spListContainer');
listContainer.innerHTML = html;
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**We can use this code in the tyscript file**

```
  public render(): void {
  this.context.msGraphClientFactory
  .getClient()
   .then((client: MSGraphClient): void => {
  // get information about the current user from the Microsoft Graph
  client
  .api('/me/outlook/tasks')
   .version('beta')
   .top(5)
   .get((error, messages: any, rawResponse?: any) => {

    this.domElement.innerHTML = `
    <div class="${ styles.container}">
      <div class="${ styles.row}">
        <div class="${ styles.column}">
          <span class="${ styles.title}">Welcome to SharePoint!</span>
          <p class="${ styles.subTitle}">Use Microsoft Graph in SharePoint Framework.</p>
          <div id="spListContainer" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>`;

    // List the latest emails based on what we got from the Graph
    this._renderEmailList(messages.value);

  });
});
}

private _renderEmailList(messages: MicrosoftGraph.Message[]): void {
let html: string = '';
for (let index = 0; index < messages.length; index++) {
  html += `<p class="${styles.description}">OutlookTasks ${index + 1} - 
${escape(messages[index].subject)}</p>`;
}

// Add the emails to the placeholder
const listContainer: Element = this.domElement.querySelector('#spListContainer');
listContainer.innerHTML = html;
}
```

**In the config folder ,go to the package-solution.json
update the code with the Web Api Permission to access the Graph API Add this piece of

```
 "webApiPermissionRequests": [
      {
        "resource": "Microsoft Graph",
        "scope": "Tasks.Read"
      }
    ],
```