# how to fetch all Planner Task in SPFX through Graph API

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts, graph-api, microsoft-planner

On the basis of  outlook task example give [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/289729/fetching-the-outlook-tasks-data-into-webpart-using-graph-api-call), I am trying to fetch all task/plan in planner associated with a user.

I am not sure if it is the right approach / set of code to fetching it.

While fetching outlook task by its "Subject", but now planner doesn't give any outcome with "Subject" key word. I even tried with "Title" instead of subject but its not recognizing "title" keyword.

**Using Render function to call Graph API**:

[image]

Here `_renderEmailfunction` is defined:

**Getting an error at `message[index].title` in code**:

[image]

Comment: Hi @abhishek23, did you try my suggestion given below? Is it working for you now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you use Microsoft Graph Toolkit in SPFx, it has an OOB componment `mgt-tasks` that could display the signed-in user's Microsoft Planner tasks.

- https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/toolkit/components/tasks

[image]

And here is a demo about how to get started with Toolkit in SPFx:

- https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/accelerate-spfx-development-with-microsoft-graph-toolkit/

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation at: [plannerTask resource type](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/plannertask?view=graph-rest-1.0), sample response for planner task will be like:

```
{
  "activeChecklistItemCount": 1024,
  "appliedCategories": {"@odata.type": "microsoft.graph.plannerAppliedCategories"},
  "assigneePriority": "String",
  "assignments": {"@odata.type": "microsoft.graph.plannerAssignments"},
  "bucketId": "String",
  "checklistItemCount": 1024,
  "completedBy": {"@odata.type": "microsoft.graph.identitySet"},
  "completedDateTime": "String (timestamp)",
  "conversationThreadId": "String",
  "createdBy": {"@odata.type": "microsoft.graph.identitySet"},
  "createdDateTime": "String (timestamp)",
  "dueDateTime": "String (timestamp)",
  "hasDescription": true,
  "id": "String (identifier)",
  "orderHint": "String",
  "percentComplete": 1024,
  "planId": "String",
  "previewType": "String",
  "referenceCount": 1024,
  "startDateTime": "String (timestamp)",
  "title": "String"
}
```

Which has `title` in it. Also, I tried it using Graph explorer and I am able to see the `title` of planner task like:

[image]

So, my guess the issue is with your data type of `messages` array you mentioned: `MicrosoftGraph.Message[]`.

Check the correct data type of planner task (from Microsoft graph library) and use it OR

Create a props with the required properties you need from planner task and use it like given at: [SPFx sample - personalTasks](https://github.com/pnp/sp-starter-kit/tree/master/solution/src/webparts/personalTasks)

Comment: Hi @abhishek, did you try this? does this answers your question? If Yes, Please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) as it will help others to find the correct answer easily. It will also remove this question from "Unanswered questions" list